# LDAP Query yields entries starting with "ldap://"

Tags: spring, ldap

I have the following search criteria in LDAP that returns a single entry :

```
Search base : OU=Employees,OU=User Accounts,dc=ad,dc=mycompany,dc=com
Filter : (&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=myuserid))
```

But when I use a larger base in my search criteria :

```
Search base : dc=ad,dc=mycompany,dc=com
Filter : (&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=myuserid))
```

then in addition to the record mentioned above, I also get three more strange entries, all of which starting with something like "`ldap://`".

This causes problem in my spring based Java application as spring's `LdapTemplate.search` is not able to parse those "unexpected" entries.

Why the second search base causes such issues ?

Comment: It must probably be *referrals* but it is hard to tell without detail. Can you add search results output in your question (at least with 1 "ldap://..." entry) ? A referral may be returned to clients as a result from a search request.

Comment: Probably these are either subdomains or Directory Partitions such as the configuration, Schema. Show more of the returned data. Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does it bother you to provide some details ?

Comment: Hi All, I was actually able to solve the issue. I changed the port from 389 to 3268. But I am still not sure of its side-effects, so still exploring it. But I could go ahead with my work.